# I can't get a fast and easy way to get keyboard events in allegro

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I am trying to make a text box in allegro and need a way of getting the ascii keycodes from the key presses. The `ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN` does not always work. I have tried getting the event to work faster but it is still slow.

If there is a way I could make this into a function that could give the Ascii char of what ever key is pressed, it would be great. (I have been looking but I cant find something easy and fast for the source code that I am using)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are looking for an [`ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_CHAR`](https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/events.html#allegro_event_key_char) event type. These events are generated every time a character is typed on the keyboard, or auto-repeated because the key was held down long enough. In other words, while `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP/DOWN` events correspond to the keyboard state, `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_CHAR` events correspond to the character input buffer state.

Comment: I am using that and it is too fast. How could I fix this? Do you need code for this.

Comment: @Mainmenu Repeat speed depends on BIOS or OS settings, or maybe otherwise.

Comment: @Mainmenu In any case, please formulate your question more precisely. Currently "it's too slow" in the question and "it's too fast" in the comment above contradict each other. Hard to answer a contradictory question.

Comment: In my program it does not get every key event. This is maybe because I am using recursive functions that call a main keyboard function many times per iteration of the main loop. Sorry for not giving the answer the first time.